# Problem with using the MvcReCaptcha library in a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvcrecaptcha

The [MvcReCaptcha](http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/) library looks very solid, and appears to have some good developer adoption, but when I tried it for the first time today, using the supplied HTML helper, my app won't run.  I have the helper in a partial view as follows:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>3. Verify that you are a human.</legend>
        @Html.GenerateCaptcha()
</fieldset>
```

I have the namespace included in web.config as instructed:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="MvcReCaptcha.Helpers"/>
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

*(Other namespaces removed for brevity)*

And I have my private and public keys defined in `appSettings`.  I can see no way that I deviate from the examples on the [CodePlex page](http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/) except that I am using Razor.  Can anyone offer some insight into what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Razor you need to add the `MvcReCaptcha.Helpers` namespace to the `<namespaces>` section of `~/Views/web.config` file and not the one in `~/web.config`.

Comment: that has 90% fixed the problem.  The helper is now rendering, but it is rendering literal script, i.e. the script is html encoded.  I had to wrap the GenerateCaptcha in Html.Raw().